# Empty list of Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

When I try to add a linked Stack Exchange account to display in my profile, the list of available Stack Exchange sites is empty.  I have over about 500 points in StackOverflow and would expect that site to be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably hit a bug; you could try a force reload to see if it is a local problem, it currently works for me. However, the Careers 2.0 devs are actively improving the site every day, so it is not out of the question that they broke something for you.

This is what the SE list looks like for me when I edit:

[image: Careers SE edit list]

The scores don't update in real time, my current Stack Overflow reputation is 18,923 for example, so the reputation shown on Careers 2.0 is a few days old.

Comment: Hopefully less than 24 hours old.  Looking right now, oldest updated records look about 13 hours old.

Comment: @NickLarsen: thinking about it, I probably was using a cached copy of the page. Certainly the numbers are far more recent for me after a reload now.

Comment: Thanks.  Waiting and refreshing did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the report John, this looks fixed now. All your accounts should be choosable on your profile.